# cascading delete using recursive method

Tags: c#, sql-server, generics, recursion, ef-power-tools

I need a way to delete a user and all it's constraints in other tables. I know of cascading delete in sql server but I can't use this for some reasons.

Let's say a user have several orders, each of that orders have some products. so I send the user in the method, it finds the orders, in a foreach loop it goes into that order and so on.

So I'm up to write a method to do this recursively; It must receive an object and find all its relations and goes through all of it.

I use EF power tools reverse engineer code first to generate these from database. here is my class:

```
public partial class myDbContext: DbContext
{
    ...

    public DbSet<Users> Users{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Orders> Orders{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Products> Products{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderProducts> OrderProducts{ get; set; }

    ...
}
public partial class Users
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders{ get; set; }
}
public partial class Orders
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual Users users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderProducts> OPs { get; set; }
}
public partial class OrderProducts
{
    public int OPID { get; set; }
    public virtual Orders orders { get; set; }
    public virtual Product products { get; set; }
}
```

using this method I am able to find all `virtual ICollection`s in the user object.

```
private void DeleteObjectAndChildren(object parent) 
    {
        using (var ctx = new myDbContext())
        {
            Type t = parent.GetType();

            //these are all virtual properties of parent
            var properties = parent.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual);
            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                var collectionType = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
                //collectionType[0] gives me the T type in ICollection<T>

                //what to do next?
            }
        }
    }
```

using `collectionType[0]` I see that it is `Orders`, I must have something like this to be able to query:

```
var childType = ctx.Set<collectionType[0]>;
```

but I can't get the right casting and all.

and if this is completely wrong, any hints would be appreciated to get me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of someone need what I was looking for. This class gets an object and finds all relations with `ICollection<T>` type and traverse through them recursively and deletes base childs.

```
public class RemoveEntityAndAllRelations
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public void SetContext(DbContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    public void RemoveChildren(object parent)
    {
        Type obj = parent.GetType();

        MethodInfo method = typeof(RemoveUserAndAllRelations).GetMethod("GetICollections");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(obj);

        var properties = (PropertyInfo[])generic.Invoke(this, null);
        if (properties.Any())
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                object child = propertyInfo.GetValue(parent, null);
                RemoveChildren(child);
            }

            try
            {
                dynamic dd = parent;
                _context.Entry(dd[0]).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                  //do what you like
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic dd = parent;
                _context.Entry(dd[0]).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                  //do what you like
            }
        }
    }
    public PropertyInfo[] GetICollections<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().Where(m =>
            m.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
            m.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
        ).ToArray();
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
using (var ctx = new myDbContext())
{
    var user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == userId);
    RemoveEntityAndAllRelations controller = new RemoveUserAndAllRelations();

    controller.SetContext(ctx);
    controller.RemoveChildren(user);

    ctx.Core_Users.Remove(user);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely inappropriate. You are performing database relational operations cursively when you ought to be using the relational model that these users were mapped in the first place.

Your application is best served as calling a stored procedure where the database language can map the tables involved and remove the correct rows for the user and their objects.

Work with your dba and the developers who desiged these tables and leave database operations to the database and framework operations to the framework.

Comment: it's just a local test application, I need to remove all the test users and things that come with it. it's not meant to be published and used in everyday use cases. besides, there are a lot of relations and tables and I can't think a way of doing this in database side.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @clifton_h feels right to me. But if you want to use youre method, you could use it to return a string to include. The use that to find and delete the object.

```
var user = users.Include("Orders.OrdersProducts");
ctx.Delete(user);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Watch out for typo's. I wrote the answer on my phone.